Lighthouse couldn't run because "The page did not paint any content" (NO_FCP)
I'm having an issue running a Lighthouse test on a page I'm testing. I think I've found the root of the problem - but I don't fully understand why it is causing a problem at the exact same script works and allows a test on another page I have.
I think the JavaScript in question is this small bit I have to fade the page in when it's loaded. Where script is located just after the opening <body> to apply a class. Then in an external main.js file an addEventListener runs.
.html file
<script>document.body.className = 'hidden';</script>

External main.js file
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.body.className = 'visible';
});

Removing this seems to fix the issue but I have the EXACT same code on another site and there is no issue. Is there an obvious reason for this?
There are scripts at the bottom of the page before the closing </body> which I thought might be clashing in someway. But I've removed all the other scripts just to be sure, just leaving the above and I still get the issue.
Really, I guess I don't need this. I could just use a 'fake' CSS only fade-in on load. But I don't understand how the same code isn't a problem elsewhere. Does it come down to the content of the page? But there's nothing major on either other than text + images.
Here's the screenshot of the Lighthouse error for reference:

Edit / Update
As a test I removed that JS (so the test works) then replaced the animation with a simple CSS fade-in with a short delay (below). And I get the same issue of the lighthouse test not running.
body {
    animation: ease-out .32s .32s forwards pageFadeIn;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes pageFadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

I get the delay is creating the issue. But what I don't understand is how the issue only exists on 1 site. But 2-3 other sites I've used this on returns Lighthouse results just fine. Is it down to the layout of each page design? And maybe how much is above 'the fold', maybe?

you can put a 
What's interesting is I removed the JS, so the test works. Then I added a simple CSS fade-in animation with a .32s delay and I get the same issue of the lighthouse test not running. It's odd how the same approach works on 2 other sites but not this - I wonder if it's dependant on the content above 'the fold' and the delay affects it depedent on layout?
